# Can PostgreSQL data files be moved from macOS to Fedora?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Can I copy the PostgreSQL data directory on a macOS (10.12.3) machine to a Fedora (25) machine then expect PostgreSQL to work on the destination?

I specifically want to avoid `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` because index creation would take forever on the (much slower) destination disk.

PostgreSQL versions are identical on both (9.6.2).  Both are 64 bit Intel machines.  The macOS machine is running PostgreSQL from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).  The Fedora machine is running PostgreSQL from [the official `yum` repo](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php)

Related question: is there somewhere in the official PostgreSQL docs that gives an answer?  I searched a bit and couldn't find it.

Comment: No, that won't work. You can only copy data directory between identical servers. The biggest problem with different OS is that Postgres relies on the operating system's support for collations. So indexes on VARCHAR column will completely be screwed up on the destination machine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If you promote your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.  (The info about collations is the type of detail I was looking for.)